# How to combine several machine learning models trained with the same target but different sets of predictors

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

The book *Hands-On Machine Learning with R* gives an overview of model stacking, but goes on to say that the same training set shall be used for the models. The vignette of *caretEnsemble* also stresses the use of the same training data.

I am curious if there is any well-established methodology, preferably implemented in R, that combines several classification models **trained with the same target but different, exclusive sets of predictors** to form a stronger model. Or is "the same target, different sets of predictors" still tantamount to the same training data? Thanks for any clarification and pointer.